# Ruby keyword arguments

Tags: ruby

I have the class. Method bar should accept argument foo with default value equal to @foo

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :foo

  def bar(foo: foo)
    p foo
  end
end
```

In irb I execute:

```
> f = Foo.new
> f.foo = 'foobar'
> f.bar
```

For ruby 2.0 result is:

```
=> "foobar"
```

and for ruby 2.1:

```
=> nil
```

Who can explain this behavior?

Comment: I can bet you that first of all your code with throw error

Comment: `def bar(foo: foo)` what is this

Comment: @RajarshiDas it's method definition.

Comment: Yep, it's method definition. You can use method call as default value for function's argument. And code is working.

Comment: @RajarshiDas http://brainspec.com/blog/2012/10/08/keyword-arguments-ruby-2-0/

Comment: @MarekLipka yes I know that it will throw error then also

Comment: @RajarshiDas the class has attar_accessor :foo, so method foo will return value of (at)foo. I define function bar with argument named foo and default value for argument foo equal to result of method foo which returns (at)foo value

Comment: I was looking it at ruby 1.9 look at my edit

Comment: Did you test this code in console? It works. It's just not expected behavior for me and I want to understand

Comment: @RajarshiDas, Versions are already mentioned in the question. (2.0, 2.1)

Comment: @RajarshiDas keyword arguments are introduced since 2.0, so no wonder this code throws error in 1.9.

Comment: ooh thanks guys I have overlooked the version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further research:

```
# (Ruby 2.1.0)
class Foo
  attr_accessor :foo

  def bar(foo: self.foo)
    foo
  end
end
f = Foo.new
f.foo = 'bar'
f.bar
# => "bar"
```

It seems Ruby 2.1.0 "initializes" local variable before evaluating the "right side" of this statement, so `foo` on the right side is treated as local variable and thus is evaluated to `nil`.

This experiment seems to confirm my hypothesis:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :foo
  def bar(foo: defined?(foo))
    foo
  end
end
# Ruby 2.0.0:
Foo.new.bar
# => "method"
# Ruby 2.1.0:
Foo.new.bar
# => "local-variable"
```

Comment: A difference between Ruby 2.0 and Ruby 2.1 is that in the latter, you can set obligatory keyword arguments. The difference in the question may or may not have something to do with this. I dont' know.

Comment: I use it to override instance variables with method call